# Text is displayed with delay

Tags: javascript, html

I want text I enter in a text field immediately to be shown in a div:

```js
function func() {
  document.getElementById("query").innerHTML = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
}
window.onload = function() {
  keyword.onkeydown = function(e) {
    func();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keyword" size="40">
<div id="query"></div>
```

It works, the only problem is, it is displayed with a delay.

So if I enter "abc", it only shows "ab". I need to enter another character, for example "abcd", so that it shows "abc".
The last character is always missing.

Here you can try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/285cz0np/

Comment: The value hasn't been updated yet at the moment the function was called. You might want to use a different `key*` event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The event is being fired `onkeydown`. Since the value of the input element hasn't changed yet, you aren't seeing the results.

You could change it to `onkeyup`, instead: [(updated example)](http://jsfiddle.net/e2bd3m0j/). Or you could set a delay before calling the function.

---

Alternatively, you could also listen to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/38y4nqkx/)

```
document.getElementById("keyword").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    document.getElementById("query").textContent = e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: `input` is also nice because it is fired in other situations related to the change of the text. Such as voice typing, pasting or automation.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because the input text value, not change until you release the key.
by using `setTimeout` you let the browser to update the value, **before** running your function (`func`)

I recommend not to change `onkeyup`, becuase you want `onkeydown`, this solution will still work using the `onkeydown` event

```
keyword.onkeydown = function (e) {
        setTimeout(func,0)
    }
```

Update Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/285cz0np/1/

I recommend you to change to `input` event. For example, if the user paste from the clipboard (by using only the mouse), your event will not fire.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the event that fires the function is `onkeydown`, so when the key is pressed down, the function reads the value of the text area. At this time it reads the data, the key that is pressed hasn't been added to the actual value yet.

An easy fix is to change the event to `onkeyup` because by the time the key is in the up state, the value of that key will be added to the value.

```
window.onload = function () {
    keyword.onkeyup = function (e) {
        func();
    }
}
```